# DirectShow Dotnet Audio Input and Renderer

Tags: .net, audio, directshow

I have been looking around for a long time, but unable to find a solution.

How can I capture Audio from a USB (directshow compliance) input device and directly pass through to PC speaker (Audio Renderer?)?

I believe this is not a difficult task, but I really can't find any example in the net.

(Using Dotnet 3.5, I can't upgrade as this is an existing application)

Thanks in advance.

-- Update to the issue.

Further looking into the code, and also some previously build samples. Now I know:

1. The source is actually from A TV Tuner (with both Video and Audio)
2. I was able to grab the graph using one of the same (I do not have source code) and export to C# using GraphEditPlus.
3. Using the exact same code from GraphEditPlus, I have manage to build the graph again, and rendered the video correctly.

Unfortunately there is still no sound. The sound is rendered using DSoundRenderer().

Any clue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Windows SDK comes with GraphEdit application, which lets you add capture filter, then add renderer filter and connect them - everything is done interactively. Alternatively you can do it with [GraphStudioNext](https://code.google.com/p/graph-studio-next/).

In .NET application, you do the same steps in code. You reference [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) first, then you create graph, create and add filters, connect their pins. DirectShow.NET samples show how individual steps are achieved.

Comment: I am actually GraphEditPlus. Unfortunately I can't see how it was all connected because the graph is not registered using DsROTEntry. Is there any alternative?

Comment: First of all, you can connect pins yourself to see how it can at all be done. Then, you can use [DirectShowSpy](http://alax.info/blog/777) to force third party app filter graph ROT registration.